# Multiproject dependency management with gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependency-management

There are currently 3 projects/git repos set up with gradle:

- app (java, android)
- backend (java, spring)
- client (java, vaadin)

Dependencies:

```
app    -> backend
client -> backend
```

Since `app` and `client` don't depend on everything in `backend` like they do not depend on spring etc. but on some model classes, I need to find a good solution for building the project.

I thought of ...

### 1. `backend` artifact

- 2 source folders like: `src/main/java` and `src/api/java`
- `api` source folder compiled as a jar artifact
- included in `app` and `client`

### 2. extend sourceSets

- add `backend/src/api/java` to `app` and `client`

### 3. new `api` project

```
app     -> api
client  -> api
backend -> api
```

### conclusion

The first and second solution does not need to have a fourth git repo and I think it's not a bad idea to have the `api` component in the `backend`, but in the context of gradle a project dependency like in 3., would be more transparent I think.

Any best practices?

Thank you for helping !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is option number 3 (create a new `api` project).

Side note: You don't need to make a separate repo for the api project, you could keep it alongside the backend project if you wanted.

**Edit: Adding Repo Layout**

If you want to have the api along side the server, you would want this layout. Then reference the API like `project(":backend:api")`

```
.
├── app
│   └── build.gradle
├── backend
│   ├── api
│   │   └── build.gradle
│   └── server
│       └── build.gradle
├── build.gradle
├── client
│   └── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

Comment: could you please describe how to map repositories, directories, gradle build files etc. and I'll mark your answer as accepted. I tried the 3rd approach and it works like a charm, but I want `api` to be part of the `backend` repo?

Comment: When you say repo what do you mean (I'm assuming you mean something like a git repo)

Comment: correct. my current directory structure is: one root dir, 4 subdirs (app, backend, client, api). the root dir is a "root" git repo with 3 submodules in it. In the root dir there is a `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` and in every subdir is a build.gradle. `app`, `backend` and `client` have a `compile project(':api')` dependency which works very well. The question now is, how to get the `backend` and the `api` in one git repo? I think they have to be in one directory. Or should I create one subdir `backend` with further two subdirs `api`, `server` and `compile project(':backend:api')` ?